# Is smooth_idf redundant?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, tf-idf

The [scikit-learn documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer.html) says

`If smooth_idf=True (the default), the constant “1” is added to the numerator and denominator of the idf as if an extra document was seen containing every term in the collection exactly once, which prevents zero divisions: idf(d, t) = log [ (1 + n) / (1 + df(d, t)) ] + 1.`

However, why would `df(d, t) = 0`? If a term doesn't occur in any text, the dictionary wouldn't have the term in the first place, would it?

Comment: That's true for "training". If you feed it a new unseen text on your old dictionary, it would be div by zero?

Comment: @ThomasJungblut But a TfidfVectorizer is only used in "training"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature is useful in `TfidfVectorizer`. According to [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html), this class can be provided with predefined `vocabulary`. If a word from vocabulary was never seen in the train data, but occures in the test, smooth_idf allows it to be successfully processed.

```
train_texts = ['apple mango', 'mango banana']
test_texts = ['apple banana', 'mango orange']
vocab = ['apple', 'mango', 'banana', 'orange']
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
vectorizer1 = TfidfVectorizer(smooth_idf=True, vocabulary=vocab).fit(train_texts)
vectorizer2 = TfidfVectorizer(smooth_idf=False, vocabulary=vocab).fit(train_texts)
print(vectorizer1.transform(test_texts).todense()) # works okay
print(vectorizer2.transform(test_texts).todense()) # raises a ValueError
```

Output:

```
[[ 0.70710678  0.          0.70710678  0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.43016528  0.          0.90275015]]
...
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```